# FragmentTransaction .add() argument giving "requires Fragment" error even though argument is a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Relevant code:

```
addDay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            ++fragIdCount;
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            String fragString = Integer.toString(fragIdCount);
            TemplateFragment1 frag2 = new TemplateFragment1(); // creating new fragment frag2 of fragment TemplateFragment1
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.templateFragmentLayout, frag2, fragString); // "frag2" is where the error is
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
        }
    });
```

TemplateFragment1 is a fragment. I'm creating a new variable that is a new TemplateFragment1 fragment. When I pass that in (frag2), I get an error saying that it requires a fragment there, but frag2 is a fragment! It's strange because I have this structure elsewhere in my program that works fine.

Edit: I did some research and I don't know why I was using the support fragment, but now I know better!

Comment: Check your imports. `android.app.Fragment` is not the same as `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `TemplateFragment1` probably extends `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` (check the imports in that class), and you're using `getFragmentManager` method which takes the parameter of type `android.app.Fragment`, which is not the same as the one from support library.

Either change the method to `getSupportFragmentManager` or the`TemplateFragment1` to extend the appropriate Fragment, `android.app.Fragment`.

Comment: Glad to have helped. Had the same problem myself a while back :)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably passing support fragment (android.support.v4.app.Fragment) and in this case you should use getSupportFragmentManager() or in the other case use android.app.Fragment